# XML - changing only one element with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML file looks like this:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Diese Grammatik wurde abgelehnt - verwenden Sie stattdessen FMPXMLRESULT. -->
<FMPDSORESULT
 xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
 <ERRORCODE>0</ERRORCODE>
 <DATABASE>Test.fmp12</DATABASE>
 <LAYOUT></LAYOUT>
 <ROW MODID="31" RECORDID="1">
  <ID_EXPORT>1</ID_EXPORT>
  <artikel_nr>14368</artikel_nr>
  <sprache>de</sprache>
  <spezifikation>&lt;row&gt;&lt;titel&gt;HDMI Port Auflösung&lt;/titel&gt;&lt;attribbut&gt;3840x2160 (UHD) @ 24/25/30 Hz&lt;/attribbut&gt;&lt;attribbut&gt;2560x1440 (QHD) @ 30/60 Hz&lt;/attribbut&gt;&lt;/row&gt;&lt;row&gt;&lt;titel&gt;Material&lt;/titel&gt;&lt;attribbut&gt;Holz&lt;/attribbut&gt;&lt;attribbut&gt;Stein&lt;/attribbut&gt;&lt;attribbut&gt;Aluminium&lt;/attribbut&gt;&lt;/row&gt;</spezifikation>
 </ROW>
</FMPDSORESULT>
```

Now my problem is, that I only want to change the output from element "**spezifikation**" because I want to disable the output-escaping like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

I found examples like this:

```
    <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

But I couldn't figure out how I can make the exception for "spezifikation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First start off with the [XSLT identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Then, you just need to add another template to match `spezifikation`. However, you need to take into account that in your XML you have a default namespace specified

```
<FMPDSORESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
```

If you are using XSLT 1.0, you need to handle this in your template match, by means of a namespace prefix...

```
<xsl:template match="fm:spezifikation" xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fm:spezifikation" xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can simplify things in XSLT 2.0, by using `xpath-default-namespace` instead.

Try this XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
     xpath-default-namespace="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="spezifikation">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked with the XSLT 1.0 Version.
What do I have to change if I want to set the disable-output-escaping="yes" option on all or on several elements.

Comment: You can specify multiple matches in the same template...`<xsl:template match="fm:spezifikation|fm:sprache" xmlns:fm="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpdsoresult">` for example.